# Normalization Exercise help convert to 1NF in Excel or Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, primary-key, normalization, transitive-dependency

Can someone please help me normalize this table. I'm having trouble recognizing my partial and transitive dependencies. I understand the concept of everything ( at least I think so)  but I'm having issues applying it.

[image: Can someone please help me normalize this table. I'm having trouble recognizing my partial and transitive dependencies]

Comment: Actually, All I need help with the 1NF

Comment: It is already in the first NF

Comment: 0th Normal Form requires: No repeating groups. First NF requires 0th NF and every row has a Primary Key defined as a (minimal) set of columns that uniquely identify each row. Without knowing the applicable business rules one cannot know what a suitable Primary Key would be.

Answer (score 0):

Not caring too much about the different NF levels, the objects you are dealing with and thus the tables you should have, are right there in the column titles:

- Item
- Delivery
- Department

Each table needs its Primary Key (DeliveryCode and DeptCode may qualify, ItemNo doesn't). Then define the relations:

`Item` -- n:1 -- `Delivery`
So you need a foreign key from `Item` to `Delivery`.

Probably the same from `Item` to `Department` (can't really tell without more information).